# В график включаются лишние элементы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Есть датасет, нужно вывести на графики каждую архитектуру из `types` по `systems`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('ap-northeast-1.csv', parse_dates=['2017-05-08 21:46:36+00:00'], dayfirst=False)
data.columns = ['Date', 'Architecture', 'OS', 'Office', 'price']
types= ['i2.2xlarge', 'i2.4xlarge', 'i2.8xlarge', 'i2.xlarge', 'i3.16xlarge', 'i3.2xlarge', 'i3.4xlarge', 'i3.8xlarge', 'i3.large', 'i3.xlarge']
systems = ['Windows', 'SUSE Linux', 'Linux/UNIX']
```

Сделал с костылем:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 2, figsize=(20,60))
i = 0
j = 0
for i in range(10):
    d_grouped_by_i = data.groupby('Architecture').get_group(types[i])
    for row in range(5):
        for column in range(2):
            for j in range(3):
                date = d_grouped_by_i.groupby('OS').get_group(systems[j])['Date']
                price = d_grouped_by_i.groupby('OS').get_group(systems[j])['price']
                axes[row, column].plot(date, price, label=types[i]+' for '+systems[j])
                axes[row, column].set_title('Price of '+types[i])
                axes[row, column].set_ylabel('price per hour, $US')
                axes[row, column].grid()
                axes[row, column].legend(loc='upper left', title='Stock prices')
                plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
                j+=1
            i += 1    
plt.show()
```

В результате с первого по девятый графики выводятся 2 архитектуры для каждой OS - на графике 6 полос данных, а нужно 3. На десятом все в порядке. Прошу помощи у многоуважаемых специалистов! Ссылка на csv - [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lNZHzYBdYqK_Ip3G-eNNUzcfiLgWDgNE/view)

Comment: Зачем сюда постить код с ошибками?  Вот что нам делать с вашей переменной data.?

Comment: @passant разве это не смысл этого форума - постить код с ошибкой и просить совета у более опытных товарищей? Я не понимаю вашего вопроса. Data - собственно сам датасет. Я внес изменения в вопрос, надеюсь я правильно Вас понял

Comment: Просить помощи - это значит сделать так, что-бы я смог воспроизвести вашу ошибку. Я взял ваш код, пытаюсь его запустить и ... ошибка. Вижу, что  что-то уже добавили. Ну, сейчас появится опять время - попробую еще раз посмотреть.

Comment: Первая непонятка. Что делает   j+=1 внутри for цикла по этому самому j ?

Comment: Перебирает элементы из списка `systems`. Я понимаю, что в цикле for это не нужно, но без этого костыля результат получается еще хуже

Comment: Аналогично, i меняется в среднем из трех циклов!!! При этом значение i  во внутреннем цикле, ну вот тут например types[i] может принимать значение от 0 до 18.

Comment: Объясню свою логику:
Мне нужно построить графики только для определенных архитектур на всех системах. Группирую я по конкретной архитектуре, получаю датасет - `d_grouped_by_i`. Затем внутри цикла для графика вытаскиваю данные по конкретной `systems` (нужны дата и прайс). Мне показалось удобным для восприятия, что по 1 архитектуре все данные будут в 1 графике.  Нагромоздил, согласен.

Comment: Логика анализу не поддается. Все что я вижу (и вы можете увидеть, просто заменив plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35) на элементарный print (i,j)) что привашей непостежимой логике эта точка проходиться  57 раз(!!!), а потом вываливается по IndexError: list index out of range. Причем что оно там реально выводит - совершенно непонятно.  Чем распутывать эти макароны, лучше переписать все по новой, используя прямую и понятную логику.